# Funções com propriedades públicas

Tags: javascript, funções

Como é possível utilizar uma função como um objeto? Sendo mais preciso, gostaria de repetir o comportamento do [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) do angular, onde é possível executar uma requisição das seguintes formas:

```
$http.get('url');

$http.post('url', data);

$http({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'url',
    ...
});
```

Perceba que a função `$http` pode ser tanto invocada diretamente como utilizada como um objeto para obter as propriedades `get` e `post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma `function` do javascript também é um objeto, e como tal ela pode ter valores e métodos atribuídos a ela como qualquer outro objeto.

O `$http` do angular é basicamente isso, uma `function` com uma série de outras `functions` adicionadas a ela como atalhos para a principal, de forma bem simplificada seria o seguinte:

```
function $http(options) {
    //código
}

$http.get = function(url) {
    return $http({method : 'get', url: url});
}

$http.post = function(url, data) {
    return $http({method : 'post', url: url, data: data});
}
```

Comment: Fiz testes setando as propriedades dentro da função (usando `this`, `var`, `return`) e não tinha jeito, quando a solução era mais fácil do que imaginei... Desta forma também é possível utilizar o `prototype` certo?

Comment: Não sei te dizer exatamente como seria com o `prototype`, mas o funcionamento dele acredito que seja diferente, no caso dele acredito que seria mesmo para objetos criados pelo `new`